# Could the solid boosters of SLS be paired together to a rescue launcher?

Tags: launch, rockets, solid-fuel, rescue-missions, shuttle-derived

The solid boosters of Shuttle/SLS fly in pairs. Could a pair of them fly without SLS, carrying a smaller second stage and payload to orbit? What capacity would it have?

A rescue launcher needs to launch on short notice, hence solid first stage. The second stage still has to be fueled. The prepared payload could be a space tug that for example could prevent a predicted debris collision in LEO from happening.

Comment: Predicted debris collision in LEO isn't currently a good rescue mission - we don't track debris accurately enough to make good conjunction predictions.  At the time of the Iridium-Cosmos collision the Iridium constellation was getting 400 conjunction notices per week in 2007 and the collision wasn't the closest predicted collision of the day (and I hear some operators get 20k+ notices a week).

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: @RussellBorogove Why? I just found a couple while cleaning up my garage... I guess that a solid launcher standing by on short notice would give more flexibility if something important is misplaced in orbit.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a great use of a big and relatively fancy SRB. Keeping something like an Athena (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athena_II) or Minotaur around might be more sensible, depending on the payload.

Comment: I may be an old cynic, but we already have something of this kind: [SM-3 ASAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SM-3).

Comment: That's... not a rescue.

Answer (score 5):

By themselves, a pair of SRBs with no payload would produce about 5500 m/s of ∆v, which gets them something more than half-way to orbit. They have a fairly poor ISP and propellant mass fraction.

If you added a 100-ton second stage using storable hydrazine-family propellants, you could get about 5 tons of payload to LEO if that's your goal.

[image]

Comment: Invisible Second Stage!

Comment: That's some serious stealth for you. NRO has cleared this shot for public release.

Comment: "Boss....we forgot something..."