# Why were the SRBs rolled out of the VAB without the rest of the Shuttle stack?

Tags: space-shuttle, srb

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/10153/26446) shows the following photo of two Shuttle solid rocket boosters, mounted on the mobile launch platform without the external tank or orbiter, and driven outside the Vehicle Assembly Building.

**Why was this done?**

---

In a comment below, @OrganicMarble gives a link to an [article](https://spaceflightnow.com/shuttle/sts134/101027srbmove/) which describes the move from High Bay 1 to High Bay 3 in October 2010.  The article also implies that the stack was using an external tank which had been damaged at the factory and repaired.  But it does not explain why moving the SRBs was done instead of simply moving the ET; I'm still looking for an adequate answer.

[image: look ma, no Shuttle]

Comment: "ummm....boss....we forgot one little thing" https://i.imgur.com/lzKjJYh.png

Comment: Both pictures somewhat reminiscent of The Invisible Man TV series

Comment: @OrganicMarble: If you know the story, please answer, as I do not know it.

Comment: @Puffin Stealth Shuttle!  The secret is out.

Comment: Huh, I forgot I added that picture, and made the same jokes. At least it was six years ago.

Comment: Speculation: With a new vehicle, you would want to test whether the trip out to the launch pad causes any damage.  So you would try it first with (boilerplate) SRBs, then try it again with an ET, and finally a whole stack.  I do seem to recall that they rolled the *Enterprise* all the way out to the launch pad, to test for fit, even though it never had any engines.

Comment: Nope, the picture in the question was taken in 2010. Here's a hint for *you*: https://spaceflightnow.com/shuttle/sts134/101027srbmove/

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Would you *please* post an answer?

Comment: Giving away the game:  https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/584723main_Wings-ch3b-pgs74-93.pdf

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I must be missing something...? I don't see any clues in that document that I can link to the two boosters going for a stroll by themselves...

Comment: It would take research to write a real answer but the gist of it is that the processing flows were disrupted when sts-135 changed from a rescue only flight to a real flight. The ET that was damaged at MAF was thought to be riskier so it was assigned to the rescue flight. When it became a real flight that ET was given to the 2nd from last flight so there could be a rescue if the tank damaged the vehicle. The decision was made late in the flows and it screwed them up.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Okay, but why move the (heavy) boosters instead of the tanks?

Comment: Consider my comment a hint, not an answer.

Comment: According to another article, ET-122 (stored in High Bay 4) was re-assigned to STS-134 late in the flow. HB4 is the opposite corner from HB 1. I would assume the logistics of moving the ET using the HB3/HB4 crane, lowering to ground in the transfer aisle, rolling to HB1/HB2 aisle (grab the ET transporter out of storage), and hooking to the HB1/HB2 crane was much more complicated than just rolling the pad with the boosters from one parking spot to another using the already present crawler.  There's a couple other things of note that were happening then, but I'm out of space in the comment.